# Error in Bash script to check existing file in Solaris

Tags: oracle, bash, unix, solaris, file-not-found

im gong to compile oracle forms on Solaris and create a script.
the script should check if .fmx is created then removes .err file.
here is my script but I've received below error

**Code to remove error files**

```
export FORMS_PATH=export FORMS_PATH=/apps/apps/frmcompile/cmteam/hla
for FILE in `ls $FORMS_PATH/*.fmx`; do  

    if exist "$FILE/*.fmx"; 
    then 
        rm $FILE/err
    fi
done
```

**Error Encountered**

> rmerr.sh[3]: exist: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You should better explain what you precisely want to do. Even after correcting the shell programming mistakes, the logic of your script is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

Regular File test is done using `"-f"`

```
export FORMS_PATH=export FORMS_PATH=/apps/apps/frmcompile/cmteam/hla
for FILE in `ls $FORMS_PATH/*.fmx`; do  
    # True if file exists and is a regular file.
    if [ -f "$FILE/*.fmx"]; then 
        rm $FILE/err
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want to do, but it is unclear where .fmx and .err files are located:

```
export FORMS_PATH=/apps/apps/frmcompile/cmteam/hla
for FILE in $FORMS_PATH/*.fmx; do
    b=$(basename $FILE)
    [ -f "$b" ] && rm ${b%fmx}err
done
```

Answer (score 1):

".err" is a file, but you list "err" here.
Some other problem here:

1. export FORMS_PATH=export FORMS_PATH=/apps/apps/frmcompile/cmteam/hla

   Replace with "FORMS_PATH=/apps/apps/frmcompile/cmteam/hla"

   2. for FILE in `ls $FORMS_PATH/*.fmx`; do
      FILE contains every file ending in ".fmx"
   3. if exist "$FILE/*.fmx"; 
      Result eg in "/apps/apps/frmcompile/cmteam/hla/blaba.fmx/*.fmx" with shell expansion and "exist" - what's this - try "test" or "[]".
   4. rm $FILE/err
      Results in "/apps/apps/frmcompile/cmteam/hla/blaba.fmx/err or .err in subfolder and that you don't like, or?

So best use this:

```
#!/bin/sh     OR #!/bin/bash
FORMS_PATH=/apps/apps/frmcompile/cmteam/hla

for fmx in $FORMS_PATH/*.fmx; do  

   # remove your files ending in .err instead of .fmx 
   /bin/rm "${fmx%.fmx}.err    # only valid with bash

done
```

Tom